# JSON serialization C# Core

Tags: c#, json, .net-core

I am new to JSON serialization. 
Case 
I am making a call to a rest API and then getting info. I want to be able to extract information from the API and use it to for calculation. I am not able to serialise my data any help/guidance will be helpful 
my code

```
    public string GlobalQuoteUri = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo";

            private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

            public GlobalQuoteProvider()
            {
                _httpClient = new HttpClient();
            }
var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(GlobalQuoteUri, cancellationToken);


                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    GlobalQuoteUriContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootGlobalQuote>(GlobalQuoteUriContent)
```

;

Classes

```
public class RootGlobalQuote
    {
        public string Metadata { get; set; }
        public List<AlphavantageGlobalQoute> GlobalQoute { get; set; }
    }
public class AlphavantageGlobalQoute
    {
        public Guid AlphavantageGlobalQouteId { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Open { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string High { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Low { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Price { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Volume { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LatestTradingDay { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string PreviousClose { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Change { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Changepercent { get; set; }
    }
```

Sample  data

```
\n    \"Global Quote\": {\n        \"01. symbol\": \"MSFT\",\n        \"02. open\": \"134.9900\",\n        \"03. high\": \"136.7200\",\n        \"04. low\": \"134.6681\",\n        \"05. price\": \"135.7400\",\n        \"06. volume\": \"16639726\",\n        \"07. latest trading day\": \"2019-08-27\",\n        \"08. previous close\": \"135.4500\",\n        \"09. change\": \"0.2900\",\n        \"10. change percent\": \"0.2141%\"\n    }\n}"
```

Comment: Please provide your unescaped JSON.

Comment: @John I am reading the data from the following url https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=MSFT&apikey=demo and then GlobalQuoteUriContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

Comment: Please provide your unescaped JSON _in the question_.

Answer (score 2):

If you look into the response, it has spaces and has numbers in each property.

{
    "Global Quote": {
        "01. symbol": "MSFT",
        "02. open": "134.9900",
        "03. high": "136.7200",
        "04. low": "134.6681",
        "05. price": "135.7400",
        "06. volume": "16639726",
        "07. latest trading day": "2019-08-27",
        "08. previous close": "135.4500",
        "09. change": "0.2900",
        "10. change percent": "0.2141%"
    }
}

So create a class as follows:

```
public class RootGlobalQuote
{
    [JsonProperty("Global Quote")]
    public GlobalQuote GlobalQuote { get; set; }
}

public class GlobalQuote
{
    [JsonProperty("01. symbol")]
    public string Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("02. open")]
    public string Open { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("03. high")]
    public string High { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("04. low")]
    public string Low { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("05. price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("06. volume")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ParseStringConverter))]
    public long Volume { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("07. latest trading day")]
    public DateTimeOffset LatestTradingDay { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("08. previous close")]
    public string PreviousClose { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("09. change")]
    public string Change { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("10. change percent")]
    public string ChangePercent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it's just what I needed to build, any further reading material you can refer will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I use these extensions

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;    
public static class MyExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize on object to bute[]
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static byte[] SerializeBinary(this object model)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
            using (JsonTextWriter jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(writer))
            {
                Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer ser = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
                ser.Serialize(jsonWriter, model);
                jsonWriter.Flush();
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
        return stream.ToArray();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize byte[] to an object of type T
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="serializedObj"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T DeserializeBinary<T>(this byte[] serializedObj)
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(serializedObj);
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (JsonTextReader jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(reader))
        {
            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer ser = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            return ser.Deserialize<T>(jsonReader);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serialize an object to JSON
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="model"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string SerializeJson(this object model)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        var json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings);
        return json;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize a string to object of T
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="json"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static T DeserializeJson<T>(this string json)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        T model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json, settings);
        return model;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Deserialize a string to object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="json"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static object DeserializeJson(this string json)
    {
        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All };
        object model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, settings);
        return model;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you generated your class from this JSON, no need to use deserializer.

```
RootGlobalQuote rg = null;
RootGlobalQuote rgOut = null;

var response = _httpClient.GetAsync(GlobalQuoteUri);
response.Wait();

var resp = response.Result;

if (resp.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var outRg = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<RootGlobalQuote>();
    outRg.Wait();
    rg = outRg.Result;
    result = new RootGlobalQuote();
}
```